# Redirect after login + $auth.setToken

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm having some difficulties with this part of my code, 
i'm sending user info to the server,getting back a token from the user, and then i want to redirect the user to a URL.. 
but, for some reasons the code goes inside the if statement (witch i thought means a success) and then keep going to the else statement.. 
also, if anybody can please explain the use of .setToken i would highly Appreciate it ...

```
 apiClient.LoginInfo(data).then(function (response) {

                            if (response.result === 'success') {


                                $auth.setToken(response);
                                 window.location.href = ('some URL'.a_href);
                                console.log('+susses');

                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('else', response);
                            }
                        }, function (error) {
                            console.log('error', error);
                        });
                    };

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

so for what i understand, $auth.setToken() takes a token inside, this token is now the authentic token of the login (at lest in this mater).  in my case i didn't set the token right (it was response.token) and also i didn't update with the project server which is my bad...

this link helped my a lot.. 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs